# How to compare tables with INNER JOIN and return true?

Tags: php, mysql

I have here a table:

```
activation
+--------+----------------+
|   id   | activation_code|
+--------+----------------+
|   0001 | 00111          |
|   0002 | 00110          |
|   0003 | 00100          |
+--------+----------------+
```

and another table:

```
device
+--------+--------------+
|   id   |activation_id |
+--------+--------------+
|   12121| 0001         |
|   12122| 0002         |
|   12123| 0003         |
|   12124| 0004         |
|   12125| 0005         |
+--------+--------------+
```

how do i get both tables and compare if the `device.activation_id == activation.id`
i want to list these devices separately, see example:

```
devices
+--------+----------+
| active |inactive  |
+--------+----------+
|   12121| 12124    |
|   12122| 12125    |
|   12123|          |
|        |          |
|        |          |
+--------+----------+
```

How can I have a very execution efficient solution using inner joint in this using PHP?

I have a solution here but its not very nice:

```
foreach ($device_query as $res_d) {
    foreach ($activation_query as $res_a) {
        if ($res_d->activation_id == $res_a->id) {
            $is_active = true;
            break;
        }
        else {
            $is_active = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use inner join? With left join it can be much more efficient.

Comment: select d.id as devive_id, a.activation_code
from device as d
left join activation as a on d.activation_id = a.id

Comment: @Musa can you please explain clearly?

Comment: When you INNER JOIN these two tables, you will get only active devices. If you do LEFT join, you will get both active and inactive, and the way to tell if the device is active is by checking if the activation code is null in the query I have written

Comment: alright thank you for elaborating. it's just that activation_code can't be null. i'm using it. also, this is just an example table, i'm dealing with a very complicated table with a lot of dependencies. but that doesnt matter, all im saying is activation_code must not be null. i found the answer below anyways. thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one SQL Select, to get both devices:

```
select 
    if(activation_code is not null, d.id, null) as active,
    if(activation_code is null, d.id, null) as inactive,
    activation_code
from device d
left join activation a
    on a.id = d.activation_id
```

If you want view the results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79abb6/13

Comment: just a follow up question, how will i get the value of activation.activation_code after the query? @randiel

Comment: just add the column activation_code, when the device is inactive, the activation_code is null, view the updated SQL Fiddle.

Comment: the code works! one thing, what does the query return? i cant understand the code fully. and i cant get the query result. @randiel

Comment: dude you don't even have to answer, i got it. thank you so much! this is more efficient!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with two separate SQL queries, one to get the active devices, and one to get the inactive devices, like so.

Active:

```
SELECT device.id AS active FROM device INNER JOIN activation ON device.activation_id=activation.id
```

Inactive:

```
SELECT device.id AS inactive FROM device WHERE device.activation_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM activation)
```

Alternately, if you want to do this all in one query, you could use the following query, and get a series of rows with each ID and one boolean value, indicating whether the other table matches or not.

```
SELECT device.id, device.activation_id IN (SELECT id FROM activation) AS activated FROM device
```

Edit: If you want to also get the activation code, you can use the following query. For devices without an activation code, that column will be NULL in the result set.

```
SELECT device.id, activation.activation_code FROM device LEFT OUTER JOIN activation ON device.activation_id=activation.id;
```

Comment: make a subquery for one column is not good practice in SQL, depends of you table size.

Comment: just a follow up question, how will i get the value of activation.activation_code after the query? @dncook

Comment: Ah, that would be a LEFT OUTER JOIN. See above.

Answer (score 1):

Most effective way to perform this operation at MySQL level; since DB systems are very effective working on its data in comparison to script that pull data and work on it.

It would be very cumbersome to do it in one go.

You might want to do something like this.

```
SELECT d.id from FROM activation as a, device as d WHERE a.id = d.activation_id;
```

This will fetch you the list of all active devices and in second query you can filter rest of the inactive devices once you have the active ones.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from db2 d2
left join db1 d1 on d2.id=d1.id
```